# Selecting only one duplicate record

Tags: sql

I have a 3-column table.

1. ID (unique)
2. code
3. time (timestamp)

I want to show code records in the specified date range like this ;

```
SELECT * FROM table 
       WHERE time >= '2018-12-13' AND time <= '2018-12-16 23:59:59.999' ORDER BY ID
```

It's work. I do not have a problem with this query. 
But I need the results of the only one row for each duplicate code records.

How can I do this with the above query?

Comment: Group By .... can be your friend ... or Select DISTINCT ....

Comment: Dbms name and sample output is helpful

Comment: Please tell us which database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) you are using, and also provide sample input and output data.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use `group by` or `distinct` clause.

```
SELECT ID, code, time 
FROM table 
WHERE time >= '2018-12-13' 
  AND time <= '2018-12-16 23:59:59.999' 
GROUP BY code 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: This query won't even run on most databases.

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table t1
where time = select min(time) from table t2
              where t2.code=t1.code
           and time >= '2018-12-13' AND time <= '2018-12-16 23:59:59.999'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DISTINCT` to your select query if you want the whole row to be one row as unique and rest duplicate rows eliminated or else `group by` can help as group by groups the multiple entries taking one entry as a group and performing aggregatiom for the other to keep both the group section and other columns in sink

```
     SELECT DISTINCT * from table 
     WHERE time >= '2018-12-13' 
       AND time <= '2018-12-16 23:59:59.999' 
     ORDER BY ID
```

or

```
     SELECT  * from table 
     WHERE time >= '2018-12-13' 
       AND time <= '2018-12-16 23:59:59.999' 
     group by code
     ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate method would be:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.id = (SELECT t2.id
              FROM table t t2
              WHERE t2.code = t.code AND
                    t2.time >= '2018-12-13' AND
                    t2.time < '2018-12-17'
              ORDER BY t2.id
              LIMIT 1
             )
ORDER BY ID;
```

In addition to being syntactically correct SQL that (apart from the `LIMIT`) should work in almost any database, it can also take advantage of an index on `(code, time, id)`.  It should be faster than an alternative using `GROUP BY`.